# Hash/array compare and merge

Tags: php, arrays

I have two data sets.

First:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Data Show Successful",
    "name0": "Al",
    "city": "",
    "pree": "R",
    "allknife": [
        {
            "name": "Folder",
            "pos": "G",
            "pos_le": "",
        },
        {
            "name": "Folder Two",
            "pos": "G",
            "pos_le": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

Second:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Data Show Successful",
    "name0": "",
    "city": "",
    "pree": "R",
    "allknife": [
        {
            "name": "Folder",
            "pos": "",
            "pos_le": "R",
        },
        {
            "name": "Folder Two",
            "pos": "G",
            "pos_le": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I compare the second data set with the first data set. If any item is empty in the second data set, then I want it to be pulled from first data set.

For instance, in the second hash `name0` is empty so the value should be replaced using the value from the first hash. Also the `allknife` array should use the same logic.

I cant understand how implement it. I am trying with array_merge(), to no avail.

Comment: Did you try it using foreach and if statements?! That would be nice start to see what to do I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things that might be optimized but I leave it to you!

```
// Just a simple example
function arfill($example, $input){
    foreach($input as $key => $value){
        if($value == ""){
            // Easy peasy set it 
            $input[$key] = $example[$key];
        }

        if(is_array($value)){
            // Little recursion here
            $input[$key] = arfill($example[$key], $input[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to replace the value of name0 with the valie that is in array2 you should use

array_replace(array1, array2)

Comment: if array 2 element empty @Sean

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea, to remove the empty entries from both arrays ( array_filter_recursive() ) and to use array_replace_recursive().

[array_replace_recursive:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

> array_replace_recursive() replaces the values of array1 with the same
>   values from all the following arrays. If a key from the first array
>   exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the value
>   from the second array. If the key exists in the second array, and not
>   the first, it will be created in the first array. If a key only exists
>   in the first array, it will be left as is. If several arrays are
>   passed for replacement, they will be processed in order, the later
>   array overwriting the previous values.

```
$arr1 = json_decode( $arr1, true );
$arr2 = json_decode( $arr2, true );

function array_filter_recursive( $input ) {
    foreach ( $input as &$value ) {
        if ( is_array( $value ) )
            $value = array_filter_recursive( $value );
    }
    return array_filter( $input );
} 

$arr = array_replace_recursive( 
    $arr1, $arr2, array_filter_recursive( $arr1 ), array_filter_recursive( $arr2 ) 
);

print_r( $arr );
/*
Array (
    [status] => OK
    [message] => Data Show Successful
    [name0] => Al
    [city] => 
    [pree] => R
    [allknife] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [name] => Folder
                    [pos] => G
                    [pos_le] => R
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [name] => Folder Two
                    [pos] => G
                    [pos_le] => 
                )
        )
)
*/
```